# PaperTrail gem ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'my_database_development.version_associations' doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-4.2, paper-trail-gem

I have encountered the problem with papertrail gem. Ruby 2.3.0, rails 4.2.5, papertrail 4.0.0.

When running

```
cap staging db:pull
```

I get

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'my_database_development.version_associations' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `version_associations`
```

What strange is that I do not have the table:

```
PaperTrail::VersionAssociation.table_exists?
#=> false
```

And they claim to have fixed the issue [here](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/commit/9542529e79b0f2cd53ddf20b61ff58dd4751b268).

Anything I can do here?

Thanks!

## EDIT

Tested with `papertrail 4.0.2` - same problem unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have the same issue with `4.0.2`? If so, please read our [contributing guide](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) then file an issue on GitHub. Thanks!

Comment: @JaredBeck sure, will do tomorrow!

Comment: I think it looks like more issue with https://github.com/sgruhier/capistrano-db-tasks not papertrail.